# i need to charge my ipod while connecting to an accessory

Tags: ipod

I'm looking to charge my iPod via USB or car charger while still being able to use a sync cable accessory with the iPod. I'm connecting an iCombie (which is a wireless adaptor) to my motorcycle helmet and want to be able to charge the iPod at the same time.

Comment: this sounds similar to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9044/, except that you need something that will work on a motorcycle

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like the [dockStubz Pass-Through connector](http://www.cablejive.com/products/dockStubz.html)

the idea is that the connector allows you to connect further 30 pin connectors to the bottom, then use a standard micro-USB cable to charge the device at the same time.